# RabbitMQ pika. Как побороть StreamLostError?

Tags: python, rabbitmq

Использую библиотеку pika для взаимодействия с RabbitMQ очередями

Для создания соединения использую:

```
def get_connection():
    credential = pika.PlainCredentials(LOGIN, PASS)
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(
        HOST, 
        5672, 
        '/', 
        credential, 
        heartbeat=0,
        blocked_connection_timeout=0
    )
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    return connection
```

Далее:

```
channel = get_connection().channel()
channel.basic_consume(queue='test', on_message_callback=run)
channel.start_consuming()
```

Функция `run` выполняет долгие вычисления (около 30 минут) и по завершении работы функции я вызываю `ch.basic_ack(method.delivery_tag)`, но получаю ошибку

`StreamLostError: Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')`

Не понимаю, что нужно сделать, чтобы подождать выполнение всей функции или вообще отключить таймаут

P.S. пробовал задавать различные значения для параметров heartbeat и blocked_connection_timeout, но результатов это не дало. Если ставлю значение обоих параметров 7200, то всего равно получаю эту ошибку после получаса работы кода

Answer (score 1):

30 минут  это много для tcp соединения. Вам бы переработать код. При синхронных вычислениях переведите тело колбэка в тред и выходите из колбэка. Тогда пика сможет посылать сердцебиения. ch передайте в тред и выполните аск из треда.

Для обработки в процессах нужно бы очередь сделать, но на пика не помню как вклиниться в главный цикл.

Comment: Спасибо, утром попробую сделать, отпишусь

Comment: Как перешел на асинкио проблем с этим стало намного меньше. Да ещё надо проверить безопасно ли вызывать аск из треда. Наверное всеже прийдется строить очередь из асков

Comment: А если я сразу же после старта делаю .join() потока, то это же бесполезно, тоже самое, что и синхронно запускать?

Comment: Для моей задачи важно, чтобы следующее сообщение не поступало, пока для предыдущего не вызван ```basic_ack```